# MVC Partialview Hiddenfor how to prepend Property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As I understand MVC Model binding for lists, the Name of the property has to be prepended to the name, otherwise the whole system cannot bind.
E.g:

```
<input type="text" name="people[0].FirstName" value="George" />
```

Unfortunately, I have the following situation:

```
public class ProjectEditModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public List<ProjectIdea> Ideas { get; set; }

        // huge list of related objects
    }

    public class ProjectIdea
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using a form the display the ProjectEditModel, and a PartialView to display the ProjectIdeas, which is quite complex, so I do not want to keep everything in one razur view.
this looks like this:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(mbox => Model.ID)

        @Html.Partial("AddAnotherProjectIdea", Model.Ideas)

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="@IndexRes.ButtonCreateNew" class="btn btn-primary" />
                @Html.ActionLink(CommonRes.ButtonToIndex, "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

and the AddAnotherProjectIdea-Partialview:

```
@model List<Domain.Entities.ProjectIdea>

<div id="IdeaList">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(mbox => Model[i].ID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => Model[i].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this construct results in an editor like
    
Which does not bind to the ProjectEditModel, because the "Ideas" name is missing from the name. Changing it manually works:

Is there an easy way to add this Property-Name to the name or can I trick the binding into accepting the name without the Propertyname?

Comment: Can you not just pass the full model `@Html.Partial("AddAnotherProjectIdea", Model)` and ajust the partial to `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Ideas.Count(); i++) { @Html.HiddenFor(mbox => Model.Ideas[i].ID)..`

Comment: I would rahter not do this, since some ajax calls are done to this specific part of the Project, e.g. adding and replacing elements.

Comment: it will not possible you have to pass either whole Model or doing it manually as you said it works.

Comment: Is `ID` the only property of `ProjectEditModel` that you need to post back (other than the collection)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke No, there are ~8 other properties. I exlcuded them for brevity.

Comment: @manish Do you know a good way to do it manually?

Comment: Not elegant, but you could change the post method to accept 2 parameters `public ActionResult(ProjectEditModel model, List<ProjectIdea> collection) {...` then assign the collection to the model.

Comment: you can change name by javascript or jquery after page loads.

Comment: @StephenMuecke not elegant, but working and more reliable than renaming stuff - could you post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the post method to accept 2 parameters, the view model and the collection, then assign the collection to the model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(ProjectEditModel model, List<ProjectIdea> collection)
{
  model.Ideas = collection;
  ...
```

Comment: This is a great answer. It's a change of thinking.